# Use Json in Fragment (textView) from OkHttp Request in seperate class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

If the button in `DietFragment` is pressed, it runs the `getJson()` method in `HttpRequestDietPlan`. Afterwards the `Json(mealId, title)` is used in the `DietFragment`.

**Problem:** `DietFragment` doesn't wait for the Request to finish.

Future isn't possible because lowest Android version needs to be 4.4

**DietFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DietFragment extends Fragment {

    Button button;
    TextView mealOne;

    public int mealId;

    public DietPlan dietPlan = new DietPlan();

    HttpRequestDietPlan hrt = new HttpRequestDietPlan();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diet, null);

        ET = rootView.findViewById(R.id.targetCalories_Input);
        Tv1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.targetCalories_Output);
        button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        mealOne = rootView.findViewById(R.id.meal1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                hrt.getJson();

                // java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

                    mealId = hrt.dietPlan.meals.get(0).mealId;
                    title = hrt.dietPlan.meals.get(0).title;
                    mealOne.setText(title);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**HttpRequestDietPlan**

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HttpRequestDietPlan {

    public DietPlan dietPlan = new DietPlan();
    public final CompletableFuture<Response> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    public void getJson() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "KEY_KEY_KEY")
                .url("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/mealplans/generate?timeFrame=day&targetCalories=2000")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray arrayMeals = json.getJSONArray("meals");

                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMeals.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = arrayMeals.getJSONObject(i);
                            Meal meal = new Meal(
                                    object.getInt("id"),
                                    object.getString("title")
                            );
                            dietPlan.meals.add(meal);
                            System.out.println(meal);
                        }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using callbacks for your request, so the getJson() return after the call has been enqueued. Then you're trying to access the result immediatly after the getJson() call, what causes an exception. 
I suggest you to revise the way you're making the request.

Comment: @RomainGoutte-Fangeas Thanks a lot, do you have a suggestion or a small hint on how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- You don't need to create a new OkHttpClient at each call, so I moved it outside the method.
- Then you can pass a callback (CallHandler) to be notified when the result of the call will be available, and update your data after the result is received.
- One more thing, about the deserialization, I suggest you to use a library (https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize your json response to an instance of a class.

PS: I didn't test this code, this is just a implementation suggestion.

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DietFragment extends Fragment {

    Button button;
    TextView mealOne;

    public int mealId;

    public DietPlan dietPlan = new DietPlan();

    HttpRequestDietPlan hrt = new HttpRequestDietPlan();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diet, null);

        ET = rootView.findViewById(R.id.targetCalories_Input);
        Tv1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.targetCalories_Output);
        button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        mealOne = rootView.findViewById(R.id.meal1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                hrt.getJson(new HttpRequestDietPlan.CallHandler(
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DietPlan dietPlan) {
                        mealId = hrt.dietPlan.meals.get(0).mealId;
                        title = hrt.dietPlan.meals.get(0).title;
                        mealOne.setText(title);
                    }
                ));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

HttpRequestDietPlan:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HttpRequestDietPlan {

    private  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public interface CallHandler {
        public void onSuccess(DietPlan dietPlan);
        public void onFailure(Exception e);
    }

    public void getJson(CallHandler callHandler) {

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "KEY_KEY_KEY")
                .url("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/mealplans/generate?timeFrame=day&targetCalories=2000")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
                e.printStackTrace();
                callHandler.onFailure(e)
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    IOException e = new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    callHandler.onFailure(e)
                } else {
                    DietPlan dietPlan = new DietPlan();
                    // Deserialize with a library here 
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray arrayMeals = json.getJSONArray("meals");

                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMeals.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = arrayMeals.getJSONObject(i);
                            Meal meal = new Meal(
                                object.getInt("id"),
                                object.getString("title")
                            );
                            dietPlan.meals.add(meal);
                            System.out.println(meal);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    callHandler.onSuccess(dietPlan)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```